# while (rs.next()) not returning all results?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I'm retrieving multiple results from a table. If there are two records that are found in the table, only one is returned. If there are three results, only two are returned. I'm not sure why this is happening as I thought that the "while (rs.next())" method would iterate through each result. Any thoughts / comments appreciated. Thanks.

```
package Test;

import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseConnection {
//Create a GUI object
static GUI GUI = new GUI();
//Initialize String array
static String[] arr = new String[5];
//Connection string to Access Database
static String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/StevenM/Desktop/TestProject.mdb";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
}

static void SelectAllFromActor(String Query) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database,"","");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query); 
    if(!rs.next()){
        GUI.NoResults();
    }
    else{
        GUI.SetActorModel();
        GUI.clearResults();
        while (rs.next()){
            arr[0] =(rs.getString("Title") +" ");
            arr[1] =(rs.getString("First_Name") +" ");
            arr[2] =(rs.getString("Last_Name") +" ");
            arr[3] =(rs.getString("Gender") +" ");
            arr[4] =(rs.getString("ID") +" ");
            GUI.AddToTable(arr,"Actor");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `rs.next()` in the `if` statement, which retrieves the first record. Then in your while loop it calls `rs.next()` however many times, but you won't ever get the first record because it's already been retrieved.

Rework it like this:

```
boolean records = false;
while(rs.next()) {
    records = true;
    // code
}
if(!records)
    GUI.NoResults();
```

Comment: Or replace the `while` with a `do-while`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That would work too, yes. Or, though I'd forgotten about it, changing the `if` condition to `rs.hasNext()` would be even better.

Comment: @Anthony Grist The method hasNext() is undefined for the type ResultSet when I change to rs.hastNext()

Comment: @Steven Well, that's what I get for trusting somebody else's answer to be correct; a `hasNext()` function seemed like a reasonable thing for `ResultSet` to have. Modifying the while loop is a better option then, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You call `rs.next` 6 lines above your `while`-statement:

```
if(!rs.next()){
    GUI.NoResults();
}
```

This way you already "process" the first result, so you always have one result less than expected. Use `first()` instead:

```
if(!rs.first()){
    GUI.NoResults();
}
```

Comment: When I use hasNext, the error "The method hasNext() is undefined for the type ResultSet" appears

Comment: Alternatively you can use a boolean and set it during the while, but a hasNext would be much cleaner from a design-perspective, see my next comment

Comment: EDIT: You can use first()

Comment: changed to first() and got the following Error "java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html 
I think it is way easier if you do the research by yourself than me reading through this and suggesting stuff. Your Exception means exactly what it says, your ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY which dsables alot of methods. Find out why this is the case or find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `rs.hasNext()` at the condition above, and at the `while-loop` leave it as it is.
When using `next()` the iterator moves to the next result, if you do it twice you lose a record.